# How to change the page that shows up AFTER customer places an order? (order success page)

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, ce-1.9.1.0, order-success-page

I would like to make some changes to the Confirmation page that comes up after the customer places an order (actually add the code for Shopper Approved) and I can't seem to locate which file and path to do that in.

Magento 1.9.1.0
porto theme (but I can also change it in the core files I guess)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes like the answer of Kul you can find it in:

```
app/design/frontend/package/theme/template/checkout/success.phtml
```

and this page is redirected from the controller:

```
app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php
```

it serves as information but it should not be modified(controller), if do you need it, it must be done properly, ie to rewrite it locally.

To add a "full survey" block After having declared it in the xml

```
    <div class="my-full-survey">
        <?php $this->getLayout()->getBlock('name.of.your.block')->toHtml(); ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: I found my success.phtml in public_html/app/design/frontend/smartwave/porto/template/checkout Is it OK to change it here?

Comment: what I need to do is add code that Shopper Approved gave me. Shopper Approved will then display what they call a "full survey" meaning it will ask customers to leave a reference...

Comment: Yes, you can customise it here, you just have to add you code of "full servey" that you have created in some block for exemple and you call it in success.phtml in some div

Comment: Look my answer !

Comment: I am not so good with these things...I've tried to modify something (I changed the word print to CAPITAL letters in the success.phtml file) and it actually reflected on the website (I see it in CAPITAL letters after I place a test order) so I was just going to paste the Shopper Approved code into that file....Is that not correct? It says this on the Shopper Approved page:

Comment: Place this code on your Thank You page.
Your Thank You page is the page that your customers are sent to immediately after they buy. Once you add the code, you need to test it to make sure that it is working properly. To see an example of what it should look like, click here. The code is this:

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript"> var sa_values = { "site":23891 };  function saLoadScript(src) { var js = window.document.createElement("script"); js.src = src; js.type = "text/javascript"; document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(js); } var d = new Date(); if (d.getTime() - 272800000 > 2484759782000) saLoadScript("//www.shopperapproved.com/thankyou/rate/33891.js"); else saLoadScript("//direct.shopperapproved.com/thankyou/rate/33891.js?d=" + d.getTime()); </script>`

Comment: I added the code and it seems to work. Is that OK or do I need to set it up differently you think?

Comment: Yes, it seems to me that is correct. Test it everywhere to make sure if it really works

Comment: You can validate my answer afterthat If it helped you

Answer (score 1):

You can check first in your theme

```
app/design/frontend/Package/YOUR_TEMPLATE_NAME/template/checkout/success.phtml
```

Or default template

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/success.phtml
```

Comment: I found my success.phtml in public_html/app/design/frontend/smartwave/porto/template/che‌​ckout Is it OK to change it here?

Comment: What I need to do is add code that Shopper Approved gave me. Shopper Approved will then display what they call a "full survey" meaning it will ask customers to leave a reference..

Comment: Yes. path is correct.