# How to make the Shopper Approved code appear only in 1 website? (I have multiple websites setup in my Magento installation)

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, magento-1, ce-1.9.1.0, order-success-page

Magento 1.9.1.0

Theme: Porto

I have placed the following code in my success.phtml file:

(in `public_html/app/design/frontend/smartwave/porto/template/checkout`)

```
<script type="text/javascript"> var sa_values = { "site":33891 };  function saLoadScript(src) { var js = window.document.createElement("script"); js.src = src; js.type = "text/javascript"; document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(js); } var d = new Date(); if (d.getTime() - 172800000 > 1484759782000) saLoadScript("//www.shopperapproved.com/thankyou/rate/33891.js"); else saLoadScript("//direct.shopperapproved.com/thankyou/rate/33891.js?d=" + d.getTime()); </script>
```

As per this post here:

[How to change the page that shows up AFTER customer places an order? (order success page)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/155334/how-to-change-the-page-that-shows-up-after-customer-places-an-order-order-succ/155339?noredirect=1#comment213252_155339)

It suppose to make a pop-up appear for the customer after the customer places an order and ask them for a reference. It works great! Except this only suppose to be for 1 website but it comes up for my second website also! (I have multiple websites setup under the same Magento installation and they all use the same PORTO theme).

**How can I make it to only appear on 1 website?**

---

Does it suppose to be exactly like this on bottom of my success.phtml file?

```
<?php if (Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId() == 1): ?>
    <script type="text/javascript"> var sa_values = { "site":33891 };  function saLoadScript(src) { var js = window.document.createElement("script"); js.src = src; js.type = "text/javascript"; document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(js); } var d = new Date(); if (d.getTime() - 172800000 > 1484759782000) saLoadScript("//www.shopperapproved.com/thankyou/rate/33891.js"); else saLoadScript("//direct.shopperapproved.com/thankyou/rate/33891.js?d=" + d.getTime()); </script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**Because it does not seem to be working (I don't see the pop-up like I did before I added this extra code in). Is the website ID 1? I assume it should be if it for the primary/first website I setup under that installation?**

Magento 1.9.1.0

The whole success.phtml file looks like this:

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE_AFL.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magentocommerce.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    design
 * @package     base_default
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2014 Magento Inc. (http://www.magentocommerce.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php  Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 */
?>
<div class="page-title">
    <h1><?php echo $this->__('Your order has been received.') ?></h1>
</div>
<?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>
<div class="form-wrap">
    <h2 class="sub-title"><?php echo $this->__('Thank you for your purchase!') ?></h2>

    <?php if ($this->getOrderId()):?>
    <?php if ($this->getCanViewOrder()) :?>
        <p><?php echo $this->__('Your order # is: %s.', sprintf('<a href="%s">%s</a>', $this->escapeHtml($this->getViewOrderUrl()), $this->escapeHtml($this->getOrderId()))) ?></p>
    <?php  else :?>
        <p><?php echo $this->__('Your order # is: %s.', $this->escapeHtml($this->getOrderId())) ?></p>
    <?php endif;?>
        <p><?php echo $this->__('You will receive an order confirmation email with details of your order and a link to track its progress.') ?></p>
    <?php if ($this->getCanViewOrder() && $this->getCanPrintOrder()) :?>
        <p>
            <?php echo $this->__('Click <a href="%s" onclick="this.target=\'_blank\'">here to PRINT</a> a copy of your order confirmation.', $this->getPrintUrl()) ?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml() ?>
        </p>
    <?php endif;?>
    <?php endif;?>

    <?php if ($this->getAgreementRefId()): ?>
        <p><?php echo $this->__('Your billing agreement # is: %s.', sprintf('<a href="%s">%s</a>', $this->escapeHtml($this->getAgreementUrl()), $this->escapeHtml($this->getAgreementRefId())))?></p>
    <?php endif;?>

    <?php if ($profiles = $this->getRecurringProfiles()):?>
    <p><?php echo $this->__('Your recurring payment profiles:'); ?></p>
    <ul class="disc">
    <?php foreach($profiles as $profile):?>
    <?php $profileIdHtml = ($this->getCanViewProfiles() ? sprintf('<a href="%s">%s</a>', $this->escapeHtml($this->getProfileUrl($profile)), $this->escapeHtml($this->getObjectData($profile, 'reference_id'))) : $this->escapeHtml($this->getObjectData($profile, 'reference_id')));?>
        <li><?php echo $this->__('Payment profile # %s: "%s".', $profileIdHtml, $this->escapeHtml($this->getObjectData($profile, 'schedule_description')))?></li>
    <?php endforeach;?>
    </ul>
    <?php endif;?>

    <div class="buttons-set">
        <button type="button" class="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Continue Shopping') ?>" onclick="window.location='<?php echo $this->getUrl() ?>'"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Continue Shopping') ?></span></span></button>
    </div>
</div>


<?php if (Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId() == 1): ?>
    <script type="text/javascript"> var sa_values = { "site":33891 };  function saLoadScript(src) { var js = window.document.createElement("script"); js.src = src; js.type = "text/javascript"; document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(js); } var d = new Date(); if (d.getTime() - 172800000 > 1484759782000) saLoadScript("//www.shopperapproved.com/thankyou/rate/33891.js"); else saLoadScript("//direct.shopperapproved.com/thankyou/rate/23891.js?d=" + d.getTime()); </script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify your code like this:

```
<?php if (Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId() == 99): ?>
    <script type="text/javascript"> var sa_values = { "site":33891 };  function saLoadScript(src) { var js = window.document.createElement("script"); js.src = src; js.type = "text/javascript"; document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(js); } var d = new Date(); if (d.getTime() - 172800000 > 1484759782000) saLoadScript("//www.shopperapproved.com/thankyou/rate/33891.js"); else saLoadScript("//direct.shopperapproved.com/thankyou/rate/33891.js?d=" + d.getTime()); </script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Just replace 99 with the id of the website you need the script for.

Comment: Where do I find the ID of the main website?

Comment: Can you please see my updated information in my original question? It does not seem to be working....I have no idea what the website ID is or where I can find it....I tried 1 but that does not seem to be working....

Comment: @Allysin to find out your website ID go to System > Manage Stores in the backend. Click on the website and in the URL the ID will be right after the `website_id`